# Is this Dirac notation Bra-Ket manipulation correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter

In my introductory condensed matter course, my teacher wrote the following for a 2-band model with eigenstates $|m\rangle,|n\rangle$. The dots indicate derivatives with respect to some arbitrary Hamiltonian parameter. However, I think there's a mistake.
$$
\langle\dot{m}|\dot{n}\rangle=\Sigma_p \langle\dot{m}|p\rangle\langle p|\dot{n}\rangle \text{ (insert identity)}
= \langle\dot{m}|m\rangle\langle m|\dot{n}\rangle + \langle\dot{m}|n\rangle\langle n|\dot{n}\rangle \text{ (2 bands)}
=\langle m|\dot{n}\rangle[\langle n|\dot{n}\rangle -\langle m|\dot{m}\rangle ],
$$
where he used the product rule: $d\langle n|n\rangle = d(1) = 0 \implies \langle n|\dot{n}\rangle +\langle \dot{n}|{n}\rangle = 0 \implies \langle n|\dot{n}\rangle = -\langle \dot{n}|{n}\rangle$.

But, shouldn't the $\langle n|\dot{n}\rangle$ term in his equation also have a minus sign, because $d\langle m|n\rangle = d(0) = 0 \implies \langle m|\dot{n}\rangle +\langle \dot{m}|{n}\rangle = 0 \implies \langle m|\dot{n}\rangle = -\langle \dot{m}|{n}\rangle$?
That is, shouldn't it be: $\langle m|\dot{n}\rangle[-\langle n|\dot{n}\rangle -\langle m|\dot{m}\rangle ]=-\langle m|\dot{n}\rangle[\langle n|\dot{n}\rangle +\langle m|\dot{m}\rangle]?$

Comment: Your answer seems right to me, but I could be missing something too.

Comment: I agree with David, something is off in your teacher's derivation.

Comment: Your argument is correct.